# How to convert a C# list of objects in a nested key:value format using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I'm building a .NET Core Web API and I have to query a lot of data from a horribly structured single table in a database. I want to convert the data in a more readable format before sending it back to the frontend clients.

I tried using GroupBy but even though the data is "separated" correctly I can't achieve the format I'm looking for: there are no nodes and no logical separation/nesting in the object.

```cs
var byDayGrouped = context.Lavori
                .Where(x => x.datetime != null)
                .GroupBy(row => new
                {
                    row.datetime.Year,
                    row.datetime.Month,
                    row.datetime.Day,
                    row.datetime.WorkerName
                })
                .ToList();
```

This is the format I'm looking for:

```
data: {
    '01.01.2019': [
        workerName: [
            work1: {
                ...
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ]
    '02.01.2019': [
        ...
    ]
}
```

This is what I get:

```
[
    [
        {
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are looking for a dictionary, as dictionaries will be serialized as JSON objects where each dictionary's key will become a property of the object.

A dictionary's key can be of any type you want, in this case you need a string as your dictionary's key and as value you will use an `IEnumerable<T>` where T is whatever type your Lavori objects are.

I'm not really sure the `GroupBy` you wrote is grouping like you want because you are also grouping by `workerName`.

Assuming you only want dates without the time part (that's what I think since you are grouping by `Year`, `Month`, `Day`) the following should work for you:

```cs
//Using .Date will remove the time part from a DateTime
var dictionary = Lavori.GroupBy(l => l.datetime.Date)
     .ToDictionary(l => l.Key.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), l => l);
```

Use this fiddle to play around with the solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rPNRvC